# Using Beautifulsoup to scrape web data - having issues pulling what i need

Tags: python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to pull the ASIN numbers for the products on the below webpage. I'm able to pull some of the other elements I need, but I cant pull the ASIN numbers. The ASIN numbers follow the 'data-asin' element of the HTML on amazon. I then want to print the output in the same way I have the other elements. Thanks for your help in advance

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

path = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)

def get_url(search_term):
    """Generate a url from search term"""
    template = 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k={}&ref=nb_sb_noss_2'
    search_term = search_term.replace(' ','+') 
    return template.format(search_term)

url = get_url('Ultrawide monitor')
print(url)

driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
results = soup.find_all('div',{'data-component-type': 's-search-result'})

item = results [0]

atag = item.h2.a
atag.text
description = atag.text.strip()
url = 'https//www.amazon.com'+atag.get('href')
price_parent = item.find('span', 'a-price')
price = price_parent.find('span', 'a-offscreen').text
rating = item.i.text
review_count = item.find('span', {'class': 'a-size-base', 'dir':     
'auto'}).text

print(description)
print(price)
print(rating)
print(review_count)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can scrape the data directly from the JSON api (and not use BeautifulSoup), for example:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

url = 'https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/football.allTradable24hrchanges?page={page}&per_page={per_page}&sort=asc'

page = 1
all_data = {}

while True:
    print('Processing page {}...'.format(page))

    data = requests.get(url.format(page=page, per_page=5000)).json()

    if data['count'] == 0:
        break

    # uncomment this to print all data:
    # from pprint import pprint
    # pprint(data)

    all_data.setdefault('id', []).extend(d['id'] for d in data['items'])
    all_data.setdefault('country', []).extend(d['country'] for d in data['items'])
    all_data.setdefault('nationalTeam', []).extend(d['nationalTeam'] for d in data['items'])
    all_data.setdefault('nationality', []).extend(d['nationality'] for d in data['items'])
    all_data.setdefault('team', []).extend(d['team'] for d in data['items'])
    all_data.setdefault('price', []).extend(d['price'] for d in data['items'])
    all_data.setdefault('scoreSell', []).extend(d['scoreSell'] for d in data['items'])
    all_data.setdefault('penceChange', []).extend(d['penceChange'] for d in data['items'])

    page += 1

df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
...
Processing page 32...
Processing page 33...
                       id      country  nationalTeam    nationality                team  price  scoreSell  penceChange
0            habib-diallo      Senegal         False        Senegal                Metz   1.19       0.71         0.09
1         sehrou-guirassy       France         False         France              Amiens   0.90       0.54         0.05
2     romain-del-castillo       France         False           None              Rennes   0.58       0.35         0.04
3          samuel-bastien      Belgium         False        Belgium      Standard Liège   0.57       0.34         0.04
4          jann-fiete-arp      Germany         False        Germany   FC Bayern München   1.43       0.86         0.03
...                   ...          ...           ...            ...                 ...    ...        ...          ...
3110      kieran-trippier      England         False        England  Atlético de Madrid   0.65       0.39        -0.01
3111        kevin-malcuit       France         False         France              Napoli   0.39       0.23        -0.01
3112       alen-halilovic      Croatia         False        Croatia       sc Heerenveen   0.36       0.22        -0.01
3113    bernardo-espinosa     Colombia         False       Colombia            Espanyol   0.18       0.11        -0.01
3114        johan-djourou  Switzerland         False  Côte d'Ivoire        Hamburger SV   0.12       0.07        -0.01

[3115 rows x 8 columns]
```

EDIT:

Screenshot from firefox with the URL:

[image]

Comment: How did you find this full URL? I took from address bar, but presumably you pulled form somewhere else?

Comment: @Jmakey I used Firefox developer tools (the Network tab) to see where the page is making requests. There is something similar in Chrome too...

Comment: requests has the json.loads under the hood. Simply put: `data = requests.get(url.format(page=page)).json()`

Comment: also, rather than making 32 requests, just increase the number returned, and get it in 1 request: `url = 'https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/football.allTradable24hrchanges?page={page}&per_page=5000&sort=asc'`

Comment: @Andrej - i cant find this anywher. apologies. this is new to me. Where in firefox / chrome do you get this address?

Comment: @Jmakey I added screenshot with the URL and reworked the example based on chitown88 comments.

Comment: Brilliant. much appreciated ! I'd give feedback, but i'm brand new and the site wont allow. thankss !

Answer (score 1):

Andrej's solution is correct, but you can slightly alter to get the full data in 1 go, and then use json_normalize. Just another way to do it so you can see.

```
import requests
import math
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

url = 'https://api-prod.footballindex.co.uk/football.allTradable24hrchanges'
per_page = 5000
page = 1
payload = {
'page':'%s' %page,
'per_page':'%s' %per_page,
'sort':'asc'}

print ('Gathering page: %s' %page)
jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
total_pages = math.ceil(jsonData['total'] / per_page)

df = json_normalize(jsonData['items'])
cols = ['id', 'country', 'nationalTeam','nationality','team', 'price', 'scoreSell', 'penceChange']
df = df[cols]

if total_pages > 1:
    for page in range(2,total_pages+1):
        print ('Gathering page: %s' %page)
        payload = {
                'page':'%s' %page,
                'per_page':'%s' %per_page,
                'sort':'asc'}

        jsonData = requests.get(url, params=payload).json()
        temp_df = json_normalize(jsonData['items'])
        df = df.append(temp_df[cols], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the website.
if the pages are 
{https://www.footballindex.co.uk/players/1, https://www.footballindex.co.uk/players/2, https://www.footballindex.co.uk/players/3...}
Make the scrape part of code to iterate on all pages

```
page = 0       
for i in range(1,n): #will iterate till n-1 page
    page = i
    result = requests.get('https://www.footballindex.co.uk/players'+str(page))

    src = result.content

    soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'lxml')

    players1 = soup.find("script").text

    players2 = players1.split('= ', 1)[1]

    players3 = json.loads(players2)


    df = pd.DataFrame(   
    [item['id'],item['country'],item['nationalTeam 
    ,item['sector'],item['nationality'],item['team']
    ,item['buyPrice'],item['sellPrice'],item['penceChange']
    ,item['changePercent']]for item in players3['playersReducer']['players']
    )
```

something like this

Comment: Ive tried running the above, but it doesnt work.

Thanks for this. But the page URL isnt different for each page on the table. It's the same.